# Datagridview row data deletion Query code doesnt work correctly

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, rowdeleting

I can able to delete rows from datagridview but cant in sql tables with query code. So basically my 'string query ' code gives an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/btrYT.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aezx8.jpg

```
private void removebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     connection.Open();
     int i;
     i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
     string query = "DELETE FROM PatientRecords WHERE Id=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
     SqlCommand delcmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
     delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index);
     MessageBox.Show("Selected Save Deleted");
}
```

Comment: try print the your query variable to make sure it is correct.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException thats error Actually my query working but just for first row . it can be about row index selection

Comment: What line are you getting that error at? Have you stepped through the code to see where it is?

Comment: @WEI_DBA string query = "DELETE FROM PatientRecords WHERE Id=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ""; this line on id equality this just working for first row of my gridview when i select second or third it gives error

Comment: Ok. What is this value, `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` being passed? Also, can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @WEI_DBA i added some imgur links to post

Comment: You don't need to use `SelectedRows[i]` if you already have the row index and it may be part of your problem. I'm not sure a row is considered selected if one of it's cells is selected. Tip: don't directly concatenate that `dataGridView1....` expression into your string. Set it to a variable so you can DEBUG and see what value it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted ' i ' variable ,  and change them with 0 now code working well thanks for helps

```
string query = "DELETE FROM PatientRecords WHERE Id=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
        SqlCommand delcmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Save Deleted");
```